# Map characters from list of strings into dictionary with index as key

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm asking to put a list of strings into a dictionary, such that the indices of the characters are the keys and the values are the combined characters.
I'm trying to get this as terse as I can.

My code:

```
a = ['apple','pear']
b = map(lambda x:dict(enumerate(x)),a)
print b
```

Output:

```
[{0: 'a', 1: 'p', 2: 'p', 3: 'l', 4: 'e'}, {0: 'p', 1: 'e', 2: 'a', 3: 'r'}]
```

Desired output:

```
{0:'ap',1:'pe',2:'pa',3:'lr',4:'e'}
```

Comment: where does pa come from? oh I see now ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Do you know if I can do this without the itertools import*, yes `map` will work to catch the shorter string as you are using python2:

```
a = ['apple','pear']
b = {i: a + b if b else a  for i, (a, b) in enumerate(map(None,*a))}

print(b)
{0: 'ap', 1: 'pe', 2: 'pa', 3: 'lr', 4: 'e'}
```

To work for either a or b being different lengths we need a little more logic:

```
b = {i: a if not b else b if not a else a + b for i,(a, b) in enumerate(map(None, *a))}
```

`map(None,*a)` will behave somewhat like `zip_longest`, None will be used as a fillvalue for the shorter string. We just check if a or b is None and do the appropriate thing based on the result.

Answer (score 4):

you want zip

```
dict(enumerate(zip(*a)))
```

or maybe izip_longest

```
dict(enumerate(itertools.izip_longest(*a,fillvalue="")))
```

if you really need to you can join the letters easy enough

```
{k:"".join(v) for k,v in result.items()}
```

Comment: Doesn't produce expected output

Comment: it just doesnt join the letters ... but i figure he can manage that

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest` (in python 2 `itertools.izip_longest`) within a dict comprehension :

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> 
>>> {i:''.join(j) for i,j in enumerate(zip_longest(*a,fillvalue=''))}
{0: 'ap', 1: 'pe', 2: 'pa', 3: 'lr', 4: 'e'}
```

Comment: good job with the join +1 for giving him a complete solution :)

Comment: @JoranBeasley I missed your edit, otherwise I'll commented that for you!

Answer (score 1):

similar solution

```
{i: x+y for i, (x,y) in enumerate(zip_longest(*a,fillvalue=''))}

{0: 'ap', 1: 'pe', 2: 'pa', 3: 'lr', 4: 'e'}
```

Comment: Do you know if I can do this without the itertools import?

Comment: then you have to write zip_longest yourself.  zip will stop at the shortest.